# I want to display the key value from a associative array? I have created an array using csv file?

Tags: arrays

```
 [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => name
            [1] => email
            [2] => contact
            [3] => address
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => santosh
            [1] => santoshm9916@gmail.com
            [2] => 9035619733
            [3] => hennur
        )
```

i want to access the [1] index(Email ID) from this array. please help......
Thank YOU

Comment: use a foreach loop to correctly modify your data

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing javascript it could be done like this if you know what key to call for your data.

```js
var arr = ([
  ["name","e-mail","contact","address"],
  ["santosh","santoshm9916@gmail.com","9035619733","hennur"],
  ["santosh2","santoshm991622222@gmail.com","90356197332","hennur2"],
  ["santosh3","santoshm9916@gmail.com","90356197333","hennur3"]
]);

console.log(arr[1][1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data :

```
$data = [[

            'name',
            'email',
            'contact',
            'address'
        ],
        [
            'santosh',
            'santoshm9916@gmail.com',
            '9035619733',
            'hennur'
        ]
      ];
```

PHP Code:

```
$title = $data[0];
      unset($data[0]);
      $table = '<table border="1">';
      $table .='<tr>';
      foreach($title as $k=>$val){
        $table.='<td>'.$val.'</td>';
      };
        $table.='<tr/>';
      foreach($data as $key=>$val){
        $table.='<tr>';
        foreach($title as $k=>$v){
            $table.='<td>'.$val[$k].'</td>';
        }
        $table.='</tr>';

      }
      $table.='</table>';
      echo $table;
```

Output :

```
name    email                   contact     address
santosh santoshm9916@gmail.com  9035619733  hennur
```